# Animation in android(make a man run)

Tags: android, animation, bitmap

I am relatively new to animation in android and just getting the feel of a couple of things.I want to know how i can make a "man"(image) run on android.The man is an icon.IF i use animation through the following code the icon just moves across the screen.How do i get the running motion.

```
       public anima1(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    cloud=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.androidicon);


    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



       protected  void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Rect re=new Rect();
    re.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight());
    Paint c=new Paint();
    c.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawRect(re,c);

    x=x+10;
    if(x==canvas.getWidth())
    {
    y=y+10;
    x=0;
    }
    if(y==canvas.getHeight())
    {
        x=0;
        y=0;
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(cloud, x, y,p);



     invalidate();



}
```

Comment: +1. I always wanted to know how to animate a running man too. If we can do this, we cam make and 2D games out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the man appear to run, you should have several different images of the man with his feet in different positions and swap out the image on every loop. Alternatively, you could use an animated GIF, but I am not sure whether Android will actually play the animation.

Comment: Do you know where i can check out the source code for doing this.

Comment: I've put up some modifications to your code that may do the trick. https://gist.github.com/1029513

Comment: @ZhehaoMao Is this(loop through several images) the method Android game makers use in making android 2D games? Hope you can reply me.. I have be pondering on this question for years! Thanks in advance!